# Unity import picture from gdrive

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

In my Unity project I want to download images from google drive. I already have a connection with gdrive and I can check what files are on the drive. At first I want to download images, but eventually obj and fbx files.
Unfortunately I do not know how to download and put on the scene picture.
Could someone explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do what you want:

1) Using **Unity3d** [WWW class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) to download images, and then retrieve 
texture using `www.texture` field.

2) Using platform specific class to download image, and then retrieve texture using **Unity3d** [native method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture.html).